# type conversion can not have aggregate operand (error in modelsim)

Tags: compiler-errors, type-conversion, vhdl

I'm novice to VHDL. I'm getting the following errors while compiling in modelsim6.5b

> 1. type conversion(to g) cannot have aggregate operand,
> 2. No feasible entries for infix operator "and",
> 3. Target type ieee.std_logic_1164.std_ulogic in variable assignment is different from             -  expression type std.stadard.integer

any help on these and the reason behind that will be helpful.

This is the package I've written

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

package enc_pkg is

    constant n       : integer := 1;
    constant k       : integer := 2;
    constant m       : integer := 3;
    constant L_total : integer := 10;
    constant L_info  : integer := 10;

    type t_g is array (1 downto 1, 3 downto 1)of std_logic;
    signal g:t_g;
    type array3_10 is array (3 downto 1, 10 downto 0) of std_logic;
    type array2_10 is array (2 downto 1, 10 downto 0) of std_logic;

    procedure rsc_encoder(
        x          : in  std_logic_vector(1 to 10);
        terminated : in  std_logic;
        y          : out array2_10);


    procedure encode_bit(input     : in  std_logic;
                         state_in  : in  std_logic_vector(1 to 2);
                         output    : out std_logic_vector(1 to 2);
                         state_out : out std_logic_vector(1 to 2));


    procedure encoderm
        (infor_bit : in  std_logic_vector(1 to 8);
         en_output : out std_logic_vector(1 to 20));

end enc_pkg;

package body enc_pkg is

    procedure rsc_encoder(
        x          : in  std_logic_vector(1 to 10);
        terminated : in  std_logic;
        y          : out array2_10)is

        variable state      : std_logic_vector(1 to 2);
        variable d_k        : std_logic;
        variable a_k        : std_logic;
        variable output_bit : std_logic_vector(1 to 2);
        variable state_out  : std_logic_vector(1 to 2);
    begin
        for i in 1 to m loop
            state(i) := '0';
        end loop;
        for i in 1 to L_total loop
            if(terminated = '0' or (terminated = '1' and i <= L_info))
            then
                d_k := x(i);
            elsif(terminated = '1' and i > L_info)then
                d_k := (g(1, 2) and state(1)) xor (g(1, 3) and state(2));
            end if;
            a_k           := (g(1, 1) and d_k) xor (g(1, 2) and state(1)) xor (g(1, 3)) and state(2));
            encode_bit(a_k, state, output_bit, state_out);
            state         := state_out;
            output_bit(1) := d_k;
            y(1, i)       := output_bit(1);
            y(2, i)       := output_bit(2);
        end loop;
    end rsc_encoder;


    procedure encode_bit(input     : in  std_logic;
                         state_in  : in  std_logic_vector(1 to 2);
                         output    : out std_logic_vector(1 to 2);
                         state_out : out std_logic_vector(1 to 2))is

        variable temp : std_logic_vector(1 to 2);
    begin
        for i in 1 to n loop
            temp(i) := g(i, 1) and input;
            for j in 2 to k loop
                temp(i) := temp(i) xor (g(i, j) and state_in(j-1));
            end loop;
        end loop;
        output    := temp;
        state_out := input & state_in(m-1);
    end encode_bit;


    procedure encoderm
        (infor_bit : in  std_logic_vector(1 to 8);
         en_output : out std_logic_vector(1 to 20))is
--type array2_10 is array (2 downto 1, 10 downto 0) of integer;
--type  array3_10 is array (3 downto 1, 10 downto 0) of integer;
        variable interleaved : std_logic_vector(1 to 10);
        variable input       : std_logic_vector(1 to 10);
        variable puncture    : std_logic;
        variable output      : array3_10;
        variable y           : array2_10;
        variable en_temp     : std_logic_vector(1 to 10);

    begin
        input := "0000000000";
        for i in 1 to 8 loop
            input(i) := infor_bit(i);
        end loop;
        rsc_encoder(input, terminated 1, y);
        for i in 1 to 10 loop
            output(1, i) := y(1, i);
            output(2, i) := y(2, i);
        end loop;

        interleaved(1)  := output(1, 1);
        interleaved(2)  := output(1, 4);
        interleaved(3)  := output(1, 7);
        interleaved(4)  := output(1, 10);
        interleaved(5)  := output(1, 2);
        interleaved(6)  := output(1, 5);
        interleaved(7)  := output(1, 8);
        interleaved(8)  := output(1, 3);
        interleaved(9)  := output(1, 6);
        interleaved(10) := output(1, 9);

        rsc_encoder(interleaved, terminated 0, y);

        for i in 1 to 10 loop
            output(3, i) := y(2, i);
        end loop;

        if puncture = '1'then
            for i in 1 to 10 loop
                for j in 1 to 3 loop
                    en_output(3*(i-1)+j) := output(j, i);
                end loop;
            end loop;
        elsif puncture = '0' then
            for i in 1 to L_total loop
                en_temp(n*(i-1)+1) := output(1, i);
                if((i rem 2) = 1)then
                    en_temp(n*i) := output(2, i);
                else

                    en_temp(n*i) := output(3, i);
                end if;
            end loop;
        end if;
        en_output := en_temp;
    end encoderm;

end enc_pkg;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take this small portion of the code:

```
type g is array (1 downto 1, 3 downto 1)of integer;
```

...

```
variable state      : std_logic_vector(1 to 2);
```

...

```
a_k           := (g(1, 1) and d_k) xor (g(1, 2) and state(1)) xor (g(1, 3)) and state(2));
```

Two things:

### Types

`g` is a type, not a signal...

Do something like this.  First you define a new type in VHDL.  Then you create (let's talk C now) a 'variable' of that new created type.  On this (again, let's talk C) 'variable', you do your stuff.

```
type t_g is array (1 downto 1, 3 downto 1)of integer;
signal g: t_g;
```

### Operators

`g(1,2)` is an integer, `state(1)` is a std_logic.  There is no `and` operator with these two types combined.  Do you need something like this:

```
if state(1) = '1' then
   ....
else
   ....
end if;
```

Comment: yeah @vermaete thanks you are exactly right g is integer and state is std_logic now I've changed g to std_logic and taken it as a signal that error was absolutely resolved but at a_k:=(g(1,1) and d_k) xor (g(1,2) and state(1)) xor (g(1,3)) and state(2)); getting a error --near "and" expecting ';' --now I cant get what the compiler is expecting.

Comment: @vjemman Could you update the code in your example and post all the errors of Modelsim.  No thanks, just upvote :-)

Comment: There is a mismatched parenthesis in the expression somewhere; it contains 8*'(' and 9*')' which may be related to the problem...

Comment: @vermaete now its showing the following errors                          1)enc_pkg.vhd(61): near "and": expecting ';'2)enc_pkg.vhd(106): near "1": expecting ')'3)enc_pkg.vhd(123): near "0": expecting ')'4)enc_pkg.vhd(146): (vcom-1272) Length of expected is 20; length of actual is 10.---particularly here in this error I expect 10 bit deprecation but it is showing error –

Comment: got resolved the issue since this error was in passing the arguments of procedure and adjusted the length parameter with that of actual.